# Connection Error with DynamoDB2 but not DynamoDB using boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am migrating some code to use boto's DynamoDB2 libraries, but I am having trouble connecting with boot.dynamodb2.  The original boto connections works fine, however.

I am using boto version 2.32.0 and python 2.7.3

```
import boto
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

access_id = '-------------' # removed
secrey_key = '--------------' # removed

tablename = 'test'
lookup = 'hash1'

conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id=access_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
table1 = conn.get_table(tablename)
item1 = table1.get_item(lookup)
print "DB1 item :: ", item1

conn2 = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=access_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
table2 = Table(tablename)
item2 = table2.get_item(hashkey=lookup)
print "DB2 item :: ", item2
```

This is the output.  Note that the item gets returned by the older dynamo call but not the boto.dynamodb2 version.

```
DB1 item ::  {'hashkey': 'hash1', 'value': 1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bototest.py", line 18, in <module>
    item2 = table2.get_item(hashkey=lookup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.31.0-py2.7.egg/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 502, in get_item
    consistent_read=consistent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.31.0-py2.7.egg/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 911, in get_item
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.31.0-py2.7.egg/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2100, in make_request
    retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.31.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 940, in _mexe
    status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.31.0-py2.7.egg/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2143, in _retry_handler
    data)
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the connection when creating the table object:

```
table2 = Table(tablename, connection=conn2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have noticed something so obvious. I've been staring at the official boto migration docs completely baffled. Unfortunately, they leave out many of the connection steps.